# Implementing Active Directory with C++ Builder

Tags: c++, active-directory, c++builder

We want to implement Active Directory using C++ Builder (10.2 Tokyo). I've managed to download the SDK from Microsoft and even used C++ Builder's implib/coff2omf utilities to convert the .Lib files to work with C++ Builder.

I've found some sample code from the Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adsi/setting-up-c---for-adsi-development), but now its trying to use a CComBSTR function from Microsoft. As I'm going through this the more I am doubting this is the correct way. Regardless, here's the line:

```
hr = pCont->Create(CComBSTR("user"), CComBSTR("cn=jeffsmith"), &pDisp );
```

Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CComBSTR` is a smart wrapper class in the ATL framework for a COM [`BSTR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069.aspx) string.  C++Builder *officially* dropped support for ATL in XE (but [you can still use it](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/C%2B%2BBuilder_Uses_DAX_for_ActiveX_and_COM#Options_for_ATL-Based_C.2B.2B_ActiveX.2FCOM_Projects)).

C++Builder's RTL has its own smart wrappers for `BSTR` ([`WideString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.WideString) and `TOleString`), for example:

```
hr = pCont->Create(WideString("user").c_bstr(), WideString("cn=jeffsmith").c_bstr(), &pDisp );
```